# How delete array of items?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have destroy function:

```
public function destroy(Tag $tag)
{
    $tag->delete();
    return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
}
```

If frontend send one id of post - all ok.
But how delete if frontend send array of post?

Comment: You might want to try with a `foreach()` ?

Comment: You would have to create another route and (potentially) create another method. Please note that if you have any model events for deleting a model that you will have to delete them individually.

Comment: I think you might want to read this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-delete-multiple-records-using-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it from filter -

```
public function destroy()
    {
        Tag::filter(\Request::only(['filter']))->delete();

        return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it,if you can get array of ids then you will delete them as

```
public function destroyArrayOfTag(array $tag){ //you can also use Request for getting post attributes

    Tag::whereIn('id',$tag)->delete();

    return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
 
}
```

where $tag is a array of ids. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass an array of ids using a delimiter. eg. comma

So your route would look like this `destroy/1,2,3,4`

Then in your controller:

```
public function destroy($ids)
{
    Tag::destroy(explode(",",$ids));
    return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
}
```

**EDIT:** You are using `DELETE` method, so your url would look something like this `api/tag/1,2,3`

Comment: It's return - [] and doesn't delete.

Comment: Are you using a resource route/controller or a custom route? Can you please provide your front end code?

Comment: Route::delete('/{tag}', 'TagController@destroy')->middleware('auth:api');

Comment: Should work. Though you are better off using something like ```Route::delete('/tag/{id}'...``` then use a method ```DELETE``` on ```tag/1,2,3```. Can I see your front end script?

Comment: No, it's only for API.

Comment: Route::group(['namespace' => 'Tags', 'prefix' => 'posts'], function () {
        Route::delete('/{tag}', 'TagController@destroy')->middleware('auth:api');
    });

Comment: Ok, I need to see what url your are using, it should be something like ```api/tag/1,2,3``` where ```1,2,3``` are the ids you want to delete

Comment: Ok, it's start work, but delete only first element of array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151253/discussion-between-cugreen-and-georg).

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you should add an array variable in your ajax.
example like this :

```
    var data =[];
```

and then fetch the array post into data. and then you can do this thing :

```
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {

        $.ajax({
        url: your_path+'/destroy/'+data[i],
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
                         notify(1,"Your Response Message");
                    }
                })
    }
```

Hope this will help you. Thank's

Comment: This will not an ideal solution as this will create multiple AJAX call. What you need to do is pass the array of ids through AJAX an delete these on the destroy function by looping through each.